# Should i serialize my exceptions if they will only be logged?

Tags: java, serialization, serialversionuid

Am working on a small internal tool which for sure will not focus on scalability.

- I am 100% sure that there will not be any external dependencies to the code i am writing now or in the future - hence no worry on [marshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066701/why-should-i-always-make-my-exceptions-serializable-net) between different app-domains.
- I will be logging the exceptions and is quiet unlikely that there will be some [post-mortem analysis](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/191295) by tools.
- does not abide by the initial design to [send exceptions throw wire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683739/why-my-exception-class-needs-to-be-serialized)

In such a scenario, do i still need my exceptions to have explicit serialVersionUID? Will serialVersionUID be helpful to just log the object?

Comment: Depends on what the logger you are using does. Though in general, if there is no need for (de) serialization of any of the exception instances, you won't need a serialization implementation.